# Drag and Drop between 2 frames by webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There are 2 frames on a webpage.
How can we drag an element from one frame , and drop it in another frame using webdriver (using any browser).

As far as I know, this can work in same frame only.

Comment: You should post here an example of your code which is not working so someone could help you improve it if it's possible.